# Select records based on multiple value of foreign key

Tags: mysql

i am currently writing query. i want to select all records from table . records will be based on mutiple values of foreign key. for example all records related to 1 and 2 both
eg. table might have

```
 id  name uid
 1    bil   3 
 2    test   3
 3    test  4
 4    test  4
 5    bil   5
 6    bil   5
```

i want to select all records related to 3 but also related to 4 in this case it is record number 2

```
SELECT id 
FROM `table` 
WHERE uid = value1 AND like_id 
       IN (SELECT like_id 
            FROM likes 
            WHERE uid = uid2) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  How is recorder with id=2 related to both records with id=3 and id=4?

Comment: yes but i never get correct answer.

Comment: i want to get all records which belongs to two values of foreign key.query i put is correct but it takes way too long time

Comment: It's not at all clear how to replicate your test case. Your query references two tables (`table` and `likes`), it references columns (presumably a column name) `like_id` from both `table` and `likes` which does not appear in your sample table. The references to `uid2` and `value1` we may presume to be literals or bind parameters, but that's not a given. This question is in serious need of improvement. It's not at all clear what the column `name` has to do with anything related to your query.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear where "`value1`" is coming from, or "`uid2`" is coming from, or where the column "`like_id`" is coming from. Those column names do not appear in your sample table. Your example query references two different table names (`table` and `likes`), yet you only show data for one example table, and that table does not have a column named `like_id`.

If we assume that "`value1`" and "`uid2`" in your query are literals, or bind parameters supplied to the query, which seems to be reasonable, given your specification (variously), of values of 1,2,3 and 4. But we're still left with "`like_id`" column. Given that it's  referenced in the SELECT list of the IN subquery, we're going to presume that's a column in the "`likes`" table, and given that it's referenced in the outer query, we're going to assume that it's a column in the (unfortunately named) `table` table.

(Bottomline, it's not at all clear how your query is returning a "correct" result, given that you've made it impossible to replicate a working test case.)

---

Given a single table, as shown in your example data, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE likes (id INT, name VARCHAR(4), uid INT);
INSERT INTO likes VALUES (1,'bil',3),(2,'test',3),(3,'test',4)
 ,(4,'test',4),(5,'bil',5),(6,'bil',5);

ALTER TABLE likes ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE likes ADD CONSTRAINT likes_ix UNIQUE KEY (uid, name);
```

Assuming that we're running a query against that single table, and that we're matching "likes" associated with uid=3 to "likes" associated with uid=4, and that the matching is done on the "name" column, then

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM `likes` t
 WHERE t.uid = 3
   AND EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM `likes` s
          WHERE s.name = t.name
            AND s.uid = 4
       )
```

That will return the `id` of the row from the `likes` table for uid=3 where we also find a row in the `likes` table for uid=4 with a matching `name` value.

Given a limited number of rows to be inspected from the `likes` table on the outer query, that gives a limited number of times a correlated subquery would need to be run, which should give reasonable performance:

For large sets, a join operation generally performs better to return an equivalent result:

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM `likes` t
  JOIN `likes` s
    ON s.name = t.name
       AND s.uid = 4
 WHERE t.uid = 3
 GROUP
    BY t.id
```

The key to optimum performance for either query is going to be appropriate indexes.